# how to use the dynamic id in javascript or jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

php code: the following code is

```
<div id="code'.$row->nid.'" class="cptext" rel="'.$url.'">'.$row->node_value.'</div> 
<div id="cd'.$row->nid.'" style="display: none; border: 1px solid #ccc; ">test test</div>';
```

the above code will generate `id`'s like this: `code1`, `code2`, `code3`, `code4`, `code5`, ...
now, in my **js** file i want to use the id value.

```
function init() {   
    clip.setHandCursor( true );
        $('this i want to put the id value in which from the above').mouseover( function() {
  }
```

Comment: As you can see from the very different answers, your question isn't very clear. You might need to explain a bit more...

Comment: i am sorry, i have updated. hope it more clearly.

Comment: Added `jquery` tag because OP's example seems to use it.

Comment: Is the missing `}` in the JS code block intentionally? I see two `{` and only one `}`... **edit** Or completely unrelated..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them in jQuery by using the [Attribute Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). My example will select the ones with an ID that starts with `code`.

```
$('[id^="code"]').whatever();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SAbLf/)

But I'd say it would be nicer and more logical to give these elements a class they share, so you could easily do selections.

```
<div id="code'.$row->nid.'" class="cptext code"...
```

and then just `$('.code')...`.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, `$('#code1').text()` will give you the text value.

UPDATE based on updated question:

Since you already have a class set:

```
$('.cptext').mouseover( function() {...} );
```

Comment: i am sorry,maybe i depict the questions unclearly. i want to use the id value. like this(code1,code2...)

Answer (score 1):

```
var theId = $(this).attr('id');
```

You can just look up the jquery documentation (or google for instance?)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myid = <?php echo $row->nid; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: i want to put the value in js file,which can't use php.

Comment: @zhuanzhou, you can't use value from PHP without using PHP (just like you can't drink water without, err, drinking water). If you want to use value from PHP in your JS files, you need to put code in place that is accessible by **both** PHP and JS file. This approach (using HTML `<script>` tag to declare a *global* variable that holds value from PHP and that can be used in JS files) seems to be a standard way how your problem is usually solved.

Comment: @binaryLV I would not say it is a standard way. I would say in most cases it just means laziness.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, with "standard" I meant "most common" rather than "advised/dictated by legal institutions". But feel free to share another approaches of passing values from PHP to JS without using AJAX (which would mean extra HTTP requests). Passing values via URL seems unhandy/dirty, same with passing values via cookies. Some hidden HTML tag (`<div style='display:none;' id='valueForJS'><?php  echo htmlspecialchars($value); ?></div>`) might be an option, though it seems to be even more dirty than defining global variable.

Comment: @binaryLV I'd certainly go with `data-` attributes. The cleanest and most semantic solution. Btw, in your meaning of `standard`, we should advocate using tables, because most sites on the net use it, so it is `more common`.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, AFAIK `data-` works only with stuff that is attached to specific HTML elements - seems to be a bit limited to me.

Comment: @binaryLV And in this case, what do you want to pass that is not attached to specific HTML elements? Other than that, if you want to send some data that cannot be attached semantically to any HTML element, could not you attach it to `body`?

Comment: @bazmegakapa, I'm not sure if author really needs to pass anything from PHP to JS *in this case*. I already upvoted your answer, as it seemed to be what author needs *in this case* (and the fact that your answer is accepted proves that). About attaching to `body` - that would be just another workaround, just as bad as declaring global JS variable.

Comment: @binaryLV I'd argue if it is just as bad :). It is not a workaround. When you look at your HTML later, you will clearly see that your `body` (let's say: your page) has some data associated with it. Clean and semantic, and easier to work with. If you just echo Javascript code with PHP, you will have a hard time finding out where that data came from and what it actually does.